# Plot multiple normal curves for each variable in an overlayed bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got the following code to get the following overlayed bar plot. I need to get 5 normal curves to show distribution for each variable, but unsure how to approach it.

[image: bar plot]

````
library(ggplot2)
  
  Graph_1$Income <- factor(Graph_1$Income,levels = c("$1 to $2,499 or loss",
                                                     "$2,500 to $4,999",
                                                     "$5,000 to $7,499",
                                                     "$7,500 to $9,999",
                                                     "$10,000 to $12,499",
                                                     "$12,500 to $14,999",
                                                     "$15,000 to $17,499",
                                                     "$17,500 to $19,999",
                                                     "$20,000 to $22,499",
                                                     "$22,500 to $24,999",
                                                     "$25,000 to $29,999",
                                                     "$30,000 to $34,999",
                                                     "$35,000 to $39,999",
                                                     "$40,000 to $44,999",
                                                     "$45,000 to $49,999",
                                                     "$50,000 to $54,999",
                                                     "$55,000 to $64,999",
                                                     "$65,000 to $74,999",
                                                     "$75,000 to $99,999",
                                                     "$100,000 or more"))
  
  ggplot(Graph_1) +
    
  geom_col(aes(x = Income, y = Black_Man, fill = "Black Man"), alpha = 1) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Income, y = Black_Woman, fill = "Black Woman"), alpha = 1) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Income, y = White_Man, fill = "White Man"), alpha = 1) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Income, y = White_Woman, fill = "White Woman"), alpha = 1) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Income, y = City_Population, fill = "City Population"), alpha = 0.1) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1))```
````

Comment: out of curiosity - what is the purpose of the normal curves, if the variables of interest in this case are clearly no normally distributed?

Comment: @Tjebo it's to make it easier to see how each demographic ranks at each income level, since some of them are currently overshadowed by others.